# Passar parâmetros de forma pythônica

Tags: python-3.x, funções, parâmetros

O driver de banco de dados que estou usando, retorna os dados de um registro em forma de tupla exemplo `('João', 32, False)`.
Estou pensando em uma forma pythônica de passar esses dados para o construtor de uma classe Pessoa, para criar um objeto com os dados contidos na tupla.
Eu havia visto em algum lugar alguma coisa a respeito de ser possível passar uma tupla como parâmetro de uma função e ela reconheceria os valores contidos na tupla como sendo o valor de cada parâmetro que a função espera.
Não tenho certeza, mas acho que vi alguma coisa nesse sentido quando iniciei os estudos em python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi corretamente, mas segue um exemplo:

```
def Pessoa(nome, idade, flag):
    print("Nome: {0}".format(nome))
    print("Idade: {0}".format(idade))
    print("Flag: {0}".format(flag))
```

Na chamada da função, basta colocar um `*` antes do parâmetro:

```
parametro = ('Joao', 32, False)
Pessoa(*parametro)
```

Ao executar:

```
Nome: Joao
Idade: 32
Flag: False
```

Mais exemplos em: [Aprenda Python](http://aprenda-python.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/funcao-com-lista-variavel-de-argumentos.html)

Comment: A resposta está correta, mas não sei se chamaria isso de pythônico. Afinal, _"Explícito é melhor do que implícito"_, e nada mais explícito numa passagem de parâmetros do que simplesmente passar os parâmetros.

Comment: Amigo, não era melhor você ter colocado a função de modo que ocupasse 1 linha apenas? Assim ficaria mais eficiente para o seu código e evitaria o uso de muitos .format()

Comment: @ViniciusMesel: Sim, é uma outra possibilidade, também. Mas o exemplo acima é apenas didático e não visa desempenho :)

Comment: @Gomiero entendo amigo! Vou add esta resposta também para poder auxilia-lo melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Matheus, assim como o @Gomiero disse na resposta anterior, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
def Pessoa(self, nome, idade, flag):
    return("Nome: {}\n\rIdade: {}\n\rFlag: {}".format(nome, idade, flag))
```

E para chamar a função:

```
parametros = (João, 35, True)
Pessoa(*parametros)
```